# Responsive Flex box

Tags: php, html, css, flexbox

I have a loop, and this loop saves everything I write, and returns it to me, as a list with one item under the other, but I need to show 2 items per line, using Responsive Flex box, but I don't know how to do it!

I imagine it's very simple, but I'm a beginner, can someone help me?

I'm doing it this way, but is wrong, i need to complete the screen

```
<ul class="flex flex-wrap gap-6" style="width: 50%; flex-basis: 100%">
     @foreach($notes as $note)
        <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg mb-4">
            <div class="p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200" style="width: 100%">
                   {{ $note->actual_date }}
                   <div class="prose prose-sm mt-4">
                   {{ $note->getNoteAsHTML() }}
                   </div>
             </div>
         </div>
       @endforeach
   </ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I need to show 2 items per line, using Responsive Flex box***

*I think I know what you are looking for, let me know if I am wrong and I can remove this answer or edit it to embellish further what your intent may be.*

This can be achieved using a ***calculated*** `min-width` on your `flex-children` along with `flex-grow`.

For example if you have reset your margin and padding and know there is no hidden of either to deal with then you can ***calculate*** a *gap* or *margin* of separation between elements along with a *percentage* on the ***flex child*** elements. Below I use a Javascript driven array to iterate over and simulate your issue of a dynamic amount of strings. I add a `flex-wrap: wrap;` along with a `gap` of `1em` on the parent element => ***flex parent***, and then add a `flex-grow` of `1`, along with a `min-width: calc(50% - 1em)`. So the `flex-grow: 1` tells css how much of the remaining space in the flex container should be assigned to the item, then `min-width: calc(50% - 1em)` tells css that the ***minimum width*** of the element should be ***50%*** of the *parents* *width* minus the `gap` size of `1em`. So basically this will only allow two elements to take up the space of each flex parents *row*, then the *parents* *`flex-wrap: wrap`* takes over and ***wraps*** your next element to the next *row* or *line*.

```js
const parent = document.querySelectorAll('.parent')

const target = parent[0];

const arr = ['first list item', 'second list item', 'third list item', 'fourth list item', 'fifth list item', 'sixth list item', 'seventh list item', 'eigth list item', 'ninth list item']
arr.forEach(val => {
  let child = document.createElement('DIV')
  child.classList.add('children')
  child.textContent = val
  target.append(child)
})
```

```css
* {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1em;
}

.children {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: calc(50% - 1em);
  background-color: green;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
</div>
```

Comment: If you feel like this worked and solved your issue, feel free to accept as answer and happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

**Use [`flex-basis`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) to make sure you get two flex items per flex line, then use [`flex-grow`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) to let them fill the remaining available space.**

`flex-basis` is the property that lets the flex items “tell” the flex container how big they’d like to be. You can specify it as a fixed `px` value, or you can specify a percentage. The percentage refers to the flex container’s inner size.

The flex container (your `ul` element) will take each element, look at its `flex-basis`, and place them on a flex line if they can still fit. For example, if you set `flex-basis: 50%`, you can fit two items per line, and the item after those two will have to go on its own line.

The challenge is that if you use `gap` in your flex container to have some spacing between the flex items, that might push your flex items onto a new line. For example, your first flex item is `flex-basis: 50%`, then you have 20px gap, and the second flex item with `flex-basis: 50%` won’t fit anymore.

**Two possible solutions**:

- manually account for the `gap` when you set your `flex-basis`. For example, if you have `gap: 10px`, you could set `flex-basis: calc(50% - 10px)`
- give your flex items a `flex-basis` that guarantees only two flex items per flex line, but leaves enough room for the `gap`. Then let the flex items grow to fill the remaining space in the flex line. For example, your two flex items with `flex-basis: 35%` will add up to 70%, then your `gap` will add a bit, and the remaining ~30% is almost definitely enough to accommodate the `gap`, unless it’s really huge

Here’s a working solution using that second idea:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 20px;
}

.flex-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 35%;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: burlywood;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">Item 1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">Item 2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">Item 3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">Item 4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">Item 5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">Item 6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">Item 7</li>
  <li class="flex-item">Item 8</li>
  <li class="flex-item">Item 9</li>
  <li class="flex-item">Item 10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, i got it

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="flex flex-wrap gap-6" style="width: 50%; flex-basis: 100%">
 @foreach($notes as $note)
    <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg mb-4">
        <div class="flex p-6 bg-white border-b border-gray-200" style="width: 100%">
               <div class="box">
               {{ $note->actual_date }}
               </div>
               <div class="box">
               {{ $note->getNoteAsHTML() }}
               </div>
         </div>
     </div>
   @endforeach
```